# How to store long pathways in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Trying to store some long pathways shortcut for all-time usage
for example Im often skipping to

```
cd C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\yy\folder_name
```

and I first tried to store it with `New-Alias` command like:

```
name: dropbox
value: cd C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\yy\folder_name
```

(also tried just the path way i.e `C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\yy\folder_name`)

But it won't work.

I've also created a profile and tried to edit the .ps1 file with:

```
New-Item alias:dropbox -Value "Set-Location \C:\Users\xx\Dropbox\yy\folder_name"
```

but this won't work either "search-path not correct" or something.

Anyone have an easy solution?

Comment: @WarrenP Please take a look at the answers to the other question and it should become obvious why I closed this question as a duplicate. *"You can create an alias for a cmdlet, but you cannot create an alias for a command with parameters and values."* Hence the simplest solution for both questions is to define a function and alias that function.

Comment: Maybe you should leave comments when closing, for just such a reason. What is obvious to you is not going to be obvious to the asker.   How do I change directory? Do that in a function.  Then what? Alias the function.   that seems like a valid comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script like this:

```
if($args[0] -eq "dir1")
{
    cd c:\projects\myProject
}
```

If you name it "ccd.ps1" and put it in your path, it should work to just type "ccd dir1"

At least it's a simple, understandable solution...

With mine I actually use a lookup in a config file with a dozen or so paths and shortcut names, but most people wouldn't mind just editing the .ps1.

Comment: By script you mean a powershell function in  script, and then load that into your powershell profile?

Comment: I just wrote a powershell script and stuck it in my path.  You could certainly do it other ways--mine won't do anything but CD though.  I should mention that after I added a directory to my path just for "helper" scripts I started to create a lot of very useful trivial scripts.  A personal spot on your path is not a bad thing to have.  OH, this assumes you have a liberal ExecutionPolicy!  If your office requires signed scripts then maybe a batch file would be better.

Comment: I always use the powershell default profile folder for that stuff ( `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` ).

Comment: re-wrote the answer/example to be more direct and less conversational.